# Cant save datetime2 in database because of foreign keys?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am really struggeling with my datetimes at my rest service. All I want is to create a new date like this:

```
Date ter = new Date()
                    {
                        StartTime = dto.StartTime,
                        EndTime = dto.EndTime,
                        Name = dto.Name,
                        Place = dto.Place,
                        Datetype = tera,
                        Type = dto.Type,
                        //Squad = new Squad(),
                        TeamNumber = mannschaft.Id
                    };
                    uow.RepDate.Create(ter);
                    //mannschaft.Dates.Add(ter);
                    uow.SaveChanges();
```

Instead of creating this date I get this error message:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

I dont have any foreign keys set in my date entity. Whats happening?

**EDIT**

My Date Entity:

```
public class Date
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    //public Squad Squad { get; set; }
    public virtual Datetype Datetype { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Datetype")]
    public int DatetypeId { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Participation> Participations { get; set; }
    public virtual Squad Squad { get; set; }
    public int TeamNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Inner Exception now (changed fields in date entity):

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.Dates_dbo.Datetypes_DatetypeId\". The conflict occurred in database \"SchoolDb\", table \"dbo.Datetypes\", column 'DatetypeId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

Datetype:

```
public class Datetype
{
    [Key]
    public int DatetypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<Squad> Squads { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

}
```

**EDIT**
The problem is here I think:

```
 Datetype tera=new Datetype();
            if (mannschaft != null)
            {
                if (!dto.DatetypeId.Equals(null)) { 
                foreach (Datetype termin in mannschaft.Datetypes)
                {
                    if (termin.DatetypeId == dto.DatetypeId)
                    {
                        tera = termin;
                    }
                }
```

Whenever I tested the service I was to lazy to create a Datetype for the date so tera was a empty datetype. So the foreign key got several problems to find the datetype. When I created a datetype everything works fine. Is there a way to make datetype optional?

Comment: Can you give more information about your database structure please? E.g. a screenshot of the entity-framework designer.

Comment: What does `datetime2` have to do with the error? The error complains that your `Date` entity is configured to have a relation with some other class that doesn't actually specify what keys to use. It's impossible to guess which relation since you didn't provide the definition of `Date` or the context configuration

Comment: please provide us with your `Date` class and it's mapping.  We cannot debug code where all you show us is assigning one value to another then calling `SaveChanges`

Comment: The fact that your `Date` contains such members as `Place` and `TeamNumber` suggests that it is misleadingly named. Maybe you meant `Meeting` or `Meetup` or suchlike.

Comment: How was the `tera` object created?  Does it exist in the `DateTypes` table?

Comment: I think I know whats the problem everytime I created a date I was to lazy to create a datetype for it so I always gave datetypeid =1. But that datetype doesnt even exists. Now when I created a datetype everything works. Is there a way to make datetype optional?

Comment: Make the foreign key ID property on your `Date` type nullable to make it optional

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for updating your question

We don't have the code for where you are getting your `DateType` entity when you assign it to your `Date` entity.  However, from the context and the errors it sounds like the `DateType` entity was not queried from the database by the context attempting to save the `Date` entity.  As such it is not being tracked by the context and when you call `SaveChanges` it attempts to insert that entity, which already exists in the database.

These are your options:

1. Query the `DateType` entity using the same context
2. Attach the `DateType` entity you have to the current context before saving it
3. Don't use the relationship assignment, instead just assign the foreign key ID

The most efficient option is the last one:

```
Date ter = new Date()
{
    StartTime = dto.StartTime,
    EndTime = dto.EndTime,
    Name = dto.Name,
    Place = dto.Place,
    //Datetype = tera,
    DatetypeId = tera.DatetypeId,
    Type = dto.Type,
    //Squad = new Squad(),
    TeamNumber = mannschaft.Id
};
uow.RepDate.Create(ter);
//mannschaft.Dates.Add(ter);
uow.SaveChanges();
```